# How can I compare if a given list of IP addresses is part of network subnet in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of different IP address which I need to compare using  netaddr function with given list of subnet in one of column in pandas data frame.

```
list=['2.2.2.2', '4.4.4.4', '5.5.5.5', '6.6.6.6\]

Df=

ID           Netblock                domain                     Comment  
0           5.6.149.0/24  .         abc.com                      xxx
1          2.3.3.2/28               example.com                  xxx
2          5.7.190.6/20             example2.com                  xxx
```

I need to compare each list of IP's with the Netblock column in dataframe if they are part of any subnet.

Comment: I am new to python and have tried writing below code but getting error  "'%r does not appear to be an IPv4 or IPv6 address' %". I am not sure if I am doing this correctly.

`an_address = ipaddress.ip_address('defined list here')
an_network=ipaddress.ip_network('defined df here')
address_in_network=an_address in an_network
print(address_in_network)`

Comment: That code cannot produce that output; for example, `%r` doesn't appear anywhere in it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: please see the example below, here i am using small list but actually i have big list, I am trying to compare if the IP in the list 'a" is part of any subnet in the list b, if the IP is not part of any subnet 
add the ip in the 'networks' list but while running I am getting too many duplicates 

`import netaddr
networks=[]
a=['2.2.2.2','3.3.3.3', '4.4.4.4', '5.5.5.5']
b=["3.3.3.0/25","1.1.1.0/24","172.15.23.0/24"]
 
for ip in a:
    for j in b:
         if IPAddress(ip) not in IPNetwork(j):
             if ip not in networks:
                 networks.append(ip)
print(networks)`